# Dividing by 100 returns 0

Tags: java

I just wanted to calculate the VAT, but when i divide by 100 to obtain the total price (price*VAT/100), but it returns me 0.0. Here's my code:

```
        a.price=sc.nextInt();

        a.vat=sc.nextInt();

        a.total=a.precio*a.iva/100;
```

'total' is defines as FLOAT instead of INT

Comment: What type is 'a'? Please provide a complete example.

Comment: As @BrianAgnew mentioned, use `BigDecimal` for financial stuff. Using `float` or `double` might lead to miscalculations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to cast the expression to `float`. I used a float literal here `100.0f`.

```
a.total= a.precio*a.iva/100.0f;
```

Comment: For financial calculations it is better to use `BigDecimal` as the others pointed out.

Comment: @UwePlonus Yes , I know that ,I just answered a basic question *Dividing by 100 returns 0* .Op should at least get the basics of integer and float airthmetic , casting and expressions correct before using Java API.

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to integer arithmetic. You want to do this with a `float` or `double` value, and quite likely you should be using `BigDecimal` to [maintain precision](http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial).

Answer (score 8):

Be careful with "/ 100" operation in Java which can lead you to miscalculations and is an expensive operation (think that the / operation is done in the binary system and not in the decimal system).

I was in a bank project where all the amounts were with two decimals in long values (for example 123.45€ were 12345), so we had to do the same operation as you ("/ 100"). We found that some amounts lead to round calculations... missing a cent (which in banking is unacceptable).

However BigDecimal handles the same operation with a simple "movePointLeft", so I recommend you to use the next code:

```
total = (BigDecimal.valueOf(price * VAT)).moveLeft(2).doubleValue()
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to cast your integers, otherwise your result will be computed as an integer before being assigned to `a.total`. Something like:

```
a.total = (float)(a.precio) * (float)(a.iva) / 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that what you're putting in your float variable is the result of operations on integers: it's an integer. In other words, `a.precio * a.iva / 100` is first evaluated to an integer (that's where you lose precision), and then this integer is assigned to `a.total` as a float.

You therefore need to specify that the operation `a.precio * a.iva / 100` has to be done on floats by casting the integer values.

Change

```
a.total=a.precio*a.iva/100;
```

to

```
a.total= ((float)a.precio)*a.iva/100;
```

Answer (score 2):

At least on of division operands must be float or double so the result is double. Otherwise the division result is integer.

```
a.total=a.precio*a.iva/100.0
```

or if you really need float, you can skip some precision

```
a.total=(float)(a.precio*a.iva/100.0)
```